# Integral of the dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over a number field $k$ and $D_1,...,D_r$ be effective Cartier divisors on $X$. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a line bundle on $X$ with $h^0(\mathcal{L}) \geq 1$. For $\mathbf{t} \in (\mathbb{R}^+)^r \setminus \{0\}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, we define the ideal
$$I(\mathbf{t},x) = \sum_{\mathbf{b} \in N(\mathbf{t},x)} \mathcal{O}_X\left ( -\sum_{i=1}^r b_iD_i \right)$$
of $\mathcal{O}_X$, where $N(\mathbf{t},x) = \{\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{N}^r:t_1b_1+...+t_rb_r \geq x\}$. We define the vector subspace
$$F(\mathbf{t})_x = H^0(X, \mathcal{L} \otimes I(\mathbf{t},x))$$
of $H^0(X,\mathcal{L})$ and let
$$\pi(\mathbf{t}) = \frac{1}{h^0(\mathcal{L})}\int^{+\infty}_0(\mathrm{dim}\,F(\mathbf{t})_x)\,dx.$$
The only thing that confuses me is this integral. What does the integral of the dimension even mean? If the dimension is positive, wouldn't the value of the integral be infinity? And how does one interpret the function $\pi$?

Comment: The dimension depends on $x$, so presumably you can prove that for $x\gg 0$, $\dim F(t)_x=0$.

Comment: @HankScorpio You are right when saying the dimension is zero for $x$ sufficiently large. But I'm not seeing what possible values $\pi$ can take, that's why I'm confused here.